Best Practices for Preventing Oscillations When Interfacing an ADC with an OPA Output
I'm working on interfacing an ADC with the output of an operational amplifier.
To mitigate signal integrity issues, my usual approach includes placing a small resistor near the OPA output and a small capacitor near the Sample and Hold (S&H) input of the ADC. This setup is designed to buffer the ADC's S&H circuit, reducing noise and improving accuracy.
In my understanding when the S&H circuit engages, it rapidly discharges the capacitor, potentially causing oscillations. These oscillations may be exacerbated by reflections in the transmission line between the OPA and the ADC. To counteract this, I was advised long time ago to add a small resistor close to the OPA to dampen any oscillations.
Conversely, a colleague suggested that the resistor should be positioned near the capacitor, closer to the ADC's S&H input, to be more effective in preventing these oscillations.
What is the best practice in this scenario? Should the resistor be placed close to the OPA output or near the capacitor at the ADC's S&H input to optimally prevent oscillations and ensure signal integrity?


What's an OPA <-- do you mean op-amp (or operational amplifier)?

How long is the trace? What is its reactance at the maximum signal frequency (in either direction: op-amp GBW, or ADC switching edge rate)?

Let's assume that you have a "really" long trace between your op-amp and the ADC input. Then the op-amp does not make much sense, because its main purpose of providing high slope currents to the ADC's S&H circuit is lost.
But still your question is valid. The 5.6 output resistor prevents oscillation of the op-amp. So if you move it towards the 220p capacitor, you will loose phase margin and risk oscillation.
But it can make sense to provide a resistor next to the cap, because this resistor has another purpose: It can provide transmission line matching and therefore reduce reflection effects from the S&H circuit.
(BTW, the op-amp circuit shown does not make much sense to me. You may want to connect the input at the positive terminal)
Summary: It can make sense to provide resistors on both ends, but ideally you don't want a transmission line between the op-amp and the ADC input.

I agree with the op-amp remark, I just drew it that way, but in my use case I have something more complex.

I think you're trying to find the best practice from the wrong premise.

These oscillations may be exacerbated by reflections in the transmission line between the OPA and the ADC

In the theory of transmission lines and signal propagation, reflections are only considered when lengths are greater than the wavelength of the signal under study. I'm pretty sure you're a long way from that.

What is the best practice in this scenario? Should the resistor be placed close to the OPA output or near the capacitor at the ADC's S&H input to optimally prevent oscillations and ensure signal integrity?

The best practice for an RC charge kickback filter is simply the shortest possible length so as not to increase the filter's Q factor. Remember a track on a printed circuit is an inductor. You should not create a second order RLC circuit.
Chapter 2.3.1.4 Input Driver Circuit of this document is very instructive https://www.tij.co.jp/lit/ug/tiducd9b/tiducd9b.pdf
